# python3: selecting which functions and modules in the package's attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, setuptools, pypi

I'm writing a python package that I intend to publish in [pypi](https://pypi.org/). My goal is that when the user imports the package then only one function is available for that user (i.e., without the containing module and the other subpackages)

To make it clearer here's a simplified example of my project

The structure of the project is as follows:

```
main_folder
 ├── setup.py
 ├── tests
 └── pkg
     ├── __init__
     ├── wrapper.py
     └── sub_pkg
          ├── __init__
          ├── mod_1.py
          └── mod_2.py
```

Where `wrapper.py` has the function `myfun` in it like so:

```
from .sub_pkg.mod_1 import specialised_function_1 
from .sub_pkg.mod_2 import specialised_function_2 

def myfun(args):
   if something1:
      result = specialised_function_1(args)
   if something2:
      result = specialised_function_2(args)
   return result
```

and what I want is when the user imports `pkg`, only `myfun` is accessible with `pkg.myfun`

**What I tried**

- I added a leading underscore to the names of the module and subpackage (i.e., the new names are `_wrapper.py` and `_sub_pkg`) to indicate that those are for internal use.
- I was able to access `myfun` directly from the package by adding `from ._wrapper import myfun` to `__init__.py`
- however I wasn't able to remove the module `wrapper` nor the subpackage `sub-pkg` completely from the attributes of `pkg`, and trying to exclude `sub-pkg` in the `setup.py` file with 
  `setuptools.setup(packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=['*.sub_pkg']))`
  caused the imports in `wrapper.py` to break

so I guess my question is, is there a way to do something like this? what is the best practices in similar situation? if not in `__init__.py` and `setup.py`, then maybe with a different sturcture?

Comment: These things are always a bit of a waste of time. There is no real "_private_" visibility in Python. From my point of view the leading underscore is the best compromise. You could probably also play with `__all__` [1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package) [2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=__all__#the-import-statement) to make the "public API" a bit more explicit. But still everything will be visible and importable one way or another.

Comment: What you don't want to do is "exclude" the "_private_" packages and modules from the distributions (`setuptools.find_packages(exclude=[...])`), because then the modules and packages are not just hidden but instead they are not packaged and distributed at all. Which means parts of the code are missing, the whole thing is broken, not usable at all.

Comment: yes, along with confirming comments, it kind of does, basically what I did with the leading underscore is the common practice in these situations, which is good enough for me 
Thank you both for the help